# Cardboard library doesn't load on intel-based devices

Tags: android, x86, intel, google-cardboard

When I load cardboard.jar + libprotobuf-java-2.6-nano.jar (Version 0.5.6) on Intel(x86) based devices, I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vrtoolkit from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
which causes: InflateException error (not able to load xml).

If I switch to the old library, cardboard.jar + libprotobuf-java-2.3-nano.jar 

Then, Intel based devices work.

V.0.5.6
[image: 0.5.6]

Old Version
[image]

It seems like v.0.5.6(latest) has lib.armeabi-v7a but no general lib.armeabi or lib.x86 SO files.

I am guessing this might be why it is causing the problem.

Is there solution? Other then use the old library?

- Intel devices I tested: Samsung Tab 3 10.1, Asus Zenfone 5

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior.

Comment: Also Galaxy S6 (ARMv8-A) doesn't work either.

Comment: Works fine on the S6 for me.

Comment: @Jorrit are you sure? Galaxy S6 uses ARMv8-A (64 bit CPU). However, I don't see 'arm64-v8a' folder included inside the cardboard.jar

Comment: arm64-v8a can execute armeabi-v7a. Yes, I am sure, since I do most of my development testing on an S6. If you are included other libraries in your project that (only?) come with arm64-v8a binaries, perhaps that causes the issue? Try stripping them out and including only armeabi-v7a libraries.

Comment: @Jorrit I found the solution for me. abiFilters did it. Hope it solves your issue too.

Comment: jclova, could you specify whether your project include other libraries that come with arm64-v8a binaries? 
Could you specify if you have this problem with the sample code? or with your own project?

As Jorrit said arm64-v8a phones can execute armv7 binaries, so this shouldn't be a problem if the only native code comes from the cardboard SDK.

Comment: @dcoz Yes, it is the problem with my project and it contains other JNI libraries that has arm64-v8a binaries. I dont have the isssue with the sample code.

Comment: @jclova, that makes sense, thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

On build.gradle file, add filters only include "armeabi-v7a" & "armeabi" so files.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi" // includes ARM SO files only, so no x86 SO file
        }
    }
    debug {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi" // includes ARM SO files only, so no x86 SO file
        }
    }
}
```

I checked Note 5, S6 working (64 bits) and checked Intel devices working as well.

<s>On Intel devices, looking around the 360 scene using gyroscope doesn't work but that's another issue.</s> [Edit]: Turns out the Intel devices which I tested didn't have the gyroscope sensor :)